# Why isn't the Shared Preferences saving the values?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I've been making a app (game) in Android Studios and testing it and it all seems to work but one thing. That is, that when I make a new high score it's either not saving properly or not being displayed properly.

```
public GamePanel(Context context) {
  super(context);
  this.mContext = context;
}





//display

public void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PrefsKeys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int oldScore = prefs.getInt("highScore", 0);
    int newScore = Player.getScore() * 3;

    //update score only if new score is higher
    if (newScore > oldScore) {
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
      editor.putInt("highScore", 0);
      editor.commit();
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("DISTANCE: " + newScore, 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
    canvas.drawText("HighScore: " + oldScore, WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
editor.putInt("highScore", 0);
```

is presumably meant to be

```
editor.putInt("highScore", newScore);
```